# Creating default attribute values for an attribute set

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set

Let's say I have an attribute set for "cats" and attribute set for "dogs."

I want each attribute set to automatically populate my product attributes with a set of default values that are different. For example, if I choose to create a "cat" product, I want the default cat attributes to load as part of the attribute set. I want to set "ear type" to "cat" rather than "dog" by default.

So basically I am looking for a way to set default attribute values for each attribute set.

How do I go about doing this?